# Using a regular expression from another file in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am doing some form validation and one of my aims is to make a big regular expression with all kinds of inappropriate words. This will be quite long and therefore I don't want to write it several times in different functions that check different parts of different forms such as titles, descriptions etc. Therefore, I was wondering how could I make a regular expression in one file and then include it in my JavaScript files? Or maybe there is a better way to do it?

right now one of my JavaScript functions has this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/\b(badword1|badword2)\b/i);
```

but of course I need it to be long, I'll be using the "Full List of Bad Words and Swear Words Banned by Google"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ES6 modules (`import / export`) or Common.js modules (`module.export / require`) to import javascript code from external files.
for example:

```js
// in your Regex file:

let pattern = new RegExp(/\b(badword1|badword2)\b/i);
export pattern

// in your main file

import patten from 'path/to/your/regex/file'
```

You can read [this article](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac) for more information about ES6 module importing/exporting.